# Creating a Custom Aggregate Function for Access Queries

Tags: database, ms-access, subquery, aggregate-functions, ms-access-2016

Most Common/Frequent/Dense Value

I'd like to find (or create a custom) **aggregate function** for use in an MS Access query, that will return the ***most common value*** (ie, *"most frequently occurring item"*) when grouped by a different field.  Below is one example of how I would use it — but I can think of others.

---

## Sample Data:

> **Scenario:**
>
> I have hourly weather forecast data.  Forecasts are `updated`
>   irregularly, one or more times a day, including a `description` like
>   "sunny" or "cloudy" (which varies hour-by-hour).
>
> ***"What is the most common `Description`, per day, per forecast?***
>
> <sub>(You can also View or Download the sample data as an `.xlsx` from  [here](http://jmp.sh/tI0rB0s)).</sub>

---

**"Raw" Data (selected fields):**

```
DateTimePST        updated            description   temperature   windSpeed
2018-02-11 02:00   2018-02-06 17:53   cloudy        -0.47         2.93
2018-02-11 02:00   2018-02-07 18:22   cloudy        2.09          8.92
2018-02-11 02:00   2018-02-08 22:48   rain          1.54          9.7
2018-02-11 03:00   2018-02-06 03:00   cloudy        0.13          4.31
2018-02-11 03:00   2018-02-06 17:53   cloudy        -0.29         2.43
2018-02-11 03:00   2018-02-07 18:22   cloudy        1.97          5.79
2018-02-11 03:00   2018-02-08 22:48   snow          1.4           10.2
2018-02-11 04:00   2018-02-06 03:00   cloudy        0.16          4.07
2018-02-11 04:00   2018-02-06 17:53   cloudy        0.02          2.78
2018-02-11 04:00   2018-02-07 18:22   cloudy        1.89          5.54
2018-02-11 04:00   2018-02-08 22:48   snow          1.44          10.75
2018-02-11 05:00   2018-02-06 03:00   cloudy        0.14          3.83
…
…
```

**Grouped:**

Grouping the data with a 'totals' query like this:

```
SELECT Int([DateTimePST]) AS DatePST, a.updated, i.description, Count(a.id) AS cnt
FROM tblWeatherData AS a 
   LEFT JOIN tblIconsToDesc AS i 
   ON a.icon = i.icon
GROUP BY Int([DateTimePST]), a.updated, i.description
ORDER BY Int([DateTimePST]), a.updated, Count(a.id) DESC;
```

...produces an ordered list showing which `Description`'s are most commonly occurring:

[image: screenshot grouped]

...but I need to list just the "Top 1" **for *each* `DatePST`|`Updated`|`Description` combination**, like this "desired output":

[image: screenshot desired]

"**Ties**" need to be either ignored (null or zero-length), or *ideally*, concatenated into a single value like `cloudy, clear`, which each had 12 records on that date|forecast).

**The "End Goal"** is crosstab-style output like this:

[image: crosstab example]

This will be used in sizable datasets so manual calculation is out of the question.  I could get it done completely with VBA but it would take a ton of work, so I'm hoping that there's a way to create a **custom aggregate function** that can be used in the "Value" section of an Access Crosstab.

In researching a solution, I found that SQL Server makes it pretty straightforward to add custom aggregate functions (like [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/user-defined-functions/create-user-defined-aggregates) or [this](http://developmentsimplyput.blogspot.ca/2013/03/creating-sql-custom-user-defined.html)), and T-SQL even has built-in functions that would probably do the job, like:

- [`DENSE_RANK`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/dense-rank-transact-sql), or maybe.
- [`TOP 1 WITH TIES`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/top-transact-sql),

...so I'm hoping there's a way to do something similar in VBA, without having to reinvent the wheel.

Any ideas are appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Access has no support for custom aggregates. You can use custom domain aggregates, though.

[Allen Browne](http://allenbrowne.com/ser-42.html) has a sample custom domain aggregate. However, these will have a major impact on performance.

To identify the most frequent value, the recommended way is to use subqueries.

Solving this problem will require multiple steps, and solving all these is too broad for SO in my opinion.

The follow up step to select the top record per category is:

```
SELECT DatePST, Updated, Description 
FROM YourGroupByQuery q 
WHERE [Count] = (   
    SELECT Max(s.[Count]) 
    FROM YourGroupByQuery s 
    WHERE s.[DatePST] = q.[DatePST] And s.[Updated] = q.[Updated]
)
```